# Create tables and fill them with my own data after migration - Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a few tables in a database that need specific data. I know I can always save the SQL command and execute them but I wonder if Laravel has some sort of specific command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seeders for test data, like @Alexey says. If you need the data to persist in all environments (e.g. local and production), you can insert the data after creating the table, with the Query Builder.

e.g.

```
<?php

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('posts')->insert([
            'title' => 'Hello, world!',
            'body' => 'This post will be created after migrating.',
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses [seeder classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding) to fill tables with data after migrations:

You need to create and register seeders and then run this command to run migration and seed the data:

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```